# Handling route alias with query params

Tags: node.js, express

**In Express, is there a better way to do the following?**

The issue is that the redirect causes a separate request. So I'm wondering if there is a better way?

```js
// List disabled users
router.get(
    '/disabled', (req,res,next) => {
         res.redirect(`${req.baseUrl}?isEnabled=false`);
    }
);

 // List multiple users
router.get('/',
   getMultipleUsers // This accepts query params for sorting, filtering, pagination, etc
)
```

Basically, `/disabled` is an "alias" for `?isEnabled=false`.

Is there a standard way of handling this in Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You could just manipulate the request and leverage the Express middleware process here e.g.</strike>

```
router.get('/disabled', (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.isEnabled = false;
  return next('/');
});
```

So my initial answer above was unfortunately a misunderstanding. It's explained in the docs that routes can be skipped (or exited early) via `next('route')` - it was my interpretation that `route` in this instance was whatever route URL you wanted to target e.g. `next('/some-url')`, that isn't the case, passing `'route'` to `next` is actually a special use-case that's handled internally, anything else passed to `next` results in an error, as explained in the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#catching-errors)

> If you pass anything to the next() function (except the string 'route'), Express regards the current request as being an error and will skip any remaining non-error handling routing and middleware functions

*It was originally my understanding that only if an Error object was passed to `next` this would happen, that clearly isn't the case*

With this understanding, and considering ordering is important for other routes you may have e.g. `/:id`, the idea of letting the request "fall through" the `/disabled` route into `/` will no longer work as it would be caught be `/:id` beforehand. This being the case, I think your best bet here is to still manually set the query parameter as per the example, but also set the URL to match the desired route e.g.

```
router.get('/disabled', (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.isEnabled = false;
  req.url = '/';
  return next();
});

router.get('/:id', ...);

router.get('/', getMultipleUsers);
```

Comment: Calling `next` function with value will go to error handler

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak Express will only go to the default error handler if an error is passed to `next` or thrown, neither of which would happen in this case.

Comment: @James. This does not work as expected. Are you sure, I need to pass `'/'` to `next`? It throws `RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:209:11)`

Comment: But if I don't pass `'/'` into `next`, then it serves the route for `/:id` and errors because not a valid id.

Comment: It works if I add `req.url = '/'` and then call `next()`. Also, the order matters, i.e. the disabled route must be defined before the other route. Can you update your answer, please?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak I owe you an apology, you were technically correct re the error handler, see explanation in answer :)

Comment: @James Regarding your updated answer, this is much better, but if the original route used middleware, e.g. to check the role or validate request parameters, then this middleware would have to be repeated for the disabled route. Is there a reason you are not changing the url using `req.url = '/'` before calling `next` (as that would pass execution on as desired)?

Comment: Thank you @James, I was taken aback, but I was in a hurry, so I left it

Comment: @Ben changing the URL is irrelevant in this example - `/disabled` and `/` are two completely separate routes now that just share the same middleware, the only reason you may want to set the URL would if you expect it to use it in `getMultipleUsers`, otherwise it won't make a difference. You are correct on having to replicate the same middleware across both routes, although that can be solved in other ways e.g. encompassing all middleware into a single function.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. However, for future reference, I haven't actually tested this. I am changing the URL to / as explained above, so no need to call the route handler function in disabled, just next is enough. Makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Ben that's actually better, and would avoid the middleware duplicate - I can update my answer to suit that. Sorry, I hadn't actually tested a lot of this myself so most of my answer was theoretical.

Comment: No problem, I wouldn't have found that solution had you not pointed me in the right direction first.